# kendo mvvm: how to define a custom css binding

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, custom-binding

Is it true that: (or am I missing something?)

- Kendo UI MVVM doesn't support css binding;

If it is, how to define a custom css binding?

I found an implementation [**here**](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2782980-add-an-mvvm-css-binding), but I only have the minified kendo js files, can anyone give a link to download the uncompressed kendo js files?

***update***

temp solution: http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2782980-add-an-mvvm-css-binding

have to modify the kendo.web.js source code.

Comment: You don't edit the kendo source, just add the binders to a separate file and load them after kendo is loaded, placing them in a script tag below kendo is probably adequate, to be sure use something like yepnope or require.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kendo UI supports the "style" binding which sets arbitrary CSS attributes. Documentation is available here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/style

On a side note you can create a custom binder without editing the source code. Here is how: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom

Finally you can use the [attr](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/attr) binding to set the `class` attribute: http://jsbin.com/ojayoq/1/edit

Comment: I know how to define normal custom bindings, <div data-bind="**css: { active: shouldBeActive }**"></div> - how to define this kind of custom binding?

Comment: Currently you can't. But you can use the one shown here: http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2782980-add-an-mvvm-css-binding It is not the same as knockout's but would do the job.

Comment: Two questions about that implementation: 1.It seems I have to modify the "kendo.web.js"/"kendo.all.js", otherwise there is exeptions; 2.can you tell me where to download the "kendo.web.js"/"kendo.all.js" files? thanks.

Comment: and for the attr binding solution, there is a problem: if the html element has some inline css classes defined, they will be overwritten: http://jsbin.com/ojayoq/4/edit.

Comment: You don't need the source code in order to create custom binders. This online demo proves that: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/custom.html The source code is available in the src directory of the distribution (not included in the trial version of course): http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/downloading-kendo

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm using this: http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2782980-add-an-mvvm-css-binding, but the source code has to be modified, otherwise there will be exceptions.

Comment: For newcomers to this question, KendoUI now supports the binding `css: { active: shouldBeActive }`

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of CSS binders at https://coderwall.com/p/gwa2jg

**CSS toggle**

```
<div data-bind="cssToggle: truthyProperty" 
     data-enabled-css="on-class" 
     data-disabled-css="off-class"></div>
```

There's also

**CSS state**

```
<div data-bind="cssState: switch"
     data-css-states="stop:red, go:green, slowdown:amber">
```

Comment: looks good, but these bindings seems to have one shortage: cannot bind two or more css classes to one div, something like: `data-bind="css: { answered: answered, answer-accepted: answerAccepted }"`

Comment: @Dean, The cssState: binder does exactly that, with as many CSS classes as there are values applicable to the property. These aren't shipped, they are custom.

Comment: What would be cool is one that matches ranges, ie. 0-25% - 26-50% etc.

Comment: I think they would be feasible, the cssState binder does text parsing on the binder expression and turns it into JSON, but there's no reason a different parser couldn't work with say, "0..25:low, 26..50:below-mid, 51..75:above-mid, 76-100:high"

Comment: @Dean the only difference with the cssState binder is that the value and CSS class name are reversed. ie. answerAccepted:answer-accepted

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example binder for the Kendo UI blog that does what I think you are looking for:
[Making Kendo UI Binders for Complex Types](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-04-30/making-kendo-ui-binders-for-complex-types)

HTML usage example:

```
<div data-bind="class: { selected: isSelected, error: hasError }">
```

This would add the "selected" class if `isSelected` is truthy, and the "error" class if `hasError` is truthy. Likewise, it would remove those classes if the bound values were falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo now (since Q2 2015) offers a [CSS class binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/css) along with the style binding.

Example:

```
<div data-bind="css: { someClass: isSomeClassEnabled }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't **[this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/style.html)** the CSS binding that you are looking for?